# SQL Function just returns "1"

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, case

This function is just returning "1"as result no matter input number when I try to get result with select.

```
Create Function dbo.LotValue (@IdAssetGroup as bit, @TdValueBase as real, @TdPrice as real, @IdRiskfactor as bit)
RETURNS real
as begin

DECLARE @Output AS real

    set @Output = 
        (case 
            when @IdAssetGroup in (1, 8) then 1
            when @IdAssetGroup in (2,3,4,6,7) then (@TdValueBase / @TdPrice)
            when @IdAssetGroup in (5) then
                    Case @IdRiskfactor
                        when 8 then 1 --BLFT
                        else 0.01
                    end
            when @IdAssetGroup in (9) then
                    case 
                        when @IdRiskfactor in (1,42,84,113) then @TdValueBase --AUD, EUR,NZD,GBP
                        when @IdRiskfactor in (25,62) then (@TdValueBase / @TdPrice) --NDF: BRL, KRW
                        else (@TdValueBase / @TdPrice) *-1 --others FX
                    end
        end)
    return @Output;
end
```

it just return "1":

```
  select dbo.lotvalue(5,20,5,42)
```

Comment: Could it be that `@IdAssetGroup` is a `bit`, which can only ever be 1 or 0...

Comment: Ow! Correct. noob error. it was supposed to be "int" thanks

Comment: You might also consider using exact numeric types instead of the approximate REAL. Once you start doing division on approximates you will get rounding errors.

Comment: @Flib `IdRiskfactor` is also a bit, but you treat it like an int later on

Comment: Also, even if you change the first calculation to int instead of bit you are going to end up with int division in the second case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are hitting your first case every time (`when @IdAssetGroup in (1, 8) then 1`) because `@IdAssetGroup` is a `bit`, which can only ever be 1 or 0.

You're doing the same with `@IdRiskFactor` as well, which I imagine needs changed.  I assume you want these to be `INT`s.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LotValue 
    (
      @IdAssetGroup as INT, 
      @TdValueBase as real, 
      @TdPrice as real, 
      @IdRiskfactor as INT
    )
RETURNS real
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `@IdAssetGroup as bit`

You may want it in `int`